Problem with traefik, keycloak and WebApp
I have a server where I deploy my services using docker-compose, among the services I have, traefik, keycloak and a WebApp.
The expected operation: The app that uses OpenIdConnect for the authorization of my WebApp, when I call the domain of my WebApp this calls the keycloak container and displays the authorization form, once the login is successful keycloak redirects to my WebApp showing the content.
The current operation: When I access the domain in my logs I get this error:
Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://example.com/realms/Investigacion/.well-known/openid-configuration'
But when I go to the link that provides the error, all the information about the realm is displayed.
So I suspect that the problem may be in traefik maybe and how it handles this call, I really don't know anymore, I tried many variations of this but nothing works.
Docker compose
services:

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v3.1
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=email@domain.cloud"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme-v1.json"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:8080"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.asDefault=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - webnet

  kcdb:
    container_name: kcdb
    image: postgres:16.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - webnet

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:26.0.7
    command: start
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: keycloak.thesispath.cloud
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8088
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_PROXY_HEADERS: 'xforwarded'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://kcdb/${POSTGRES_DB}
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    depends_on:
      - kcdb
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`keycloak.domain.cloud`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    networks:
      - webnet

  webApp:
    image: webApp:v6.1
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webApp.rule=Host(`webApp.domain.cloud`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webApp.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webApp.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    networks:
      - webnet
      
networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  pgdata:
  letsencrypt:

My OpenIdCOnnect config on Program.cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:Authority"];
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:Metadata"]);
    if (options.RequireHttpsMetadata)
    {
        options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:MetaAddress"];
    }
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.CallbackPath = "/login-callback";
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/logout-callback";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
        RoleClaimType = "roles"
    };

})

My appsettings.json config for this
    "OpenId": {
      "ClientId": "InvestigacionClient",
      "ClientSecret": "ClientSecret",
      "Authority": "https://example.com/realms/Investigacion",
      "MetaAddress": "https://example.com/realms/Investigacion/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      "Metadata": true
    }

Error
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://example.com/realms/Investigacion/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '12/16/2024 22:34:40 +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://example.com/realms/Investigacion/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
       ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
       ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)


Did you scan through the documentation at https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy?
